# Unable to deserialize error response from Graph API due to an invalid character

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

The error response I get from Graph API is below.

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c2b32b83-5ccf-4385-bee1-33afcc31deb0",
      "date": "2016-07-25T00:25:16"
    }
  }
}

When I try to deserialize the response into my own error object i get an error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

Copy the above JSON and try validate using this tool
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Anyone else having the same issue?

---

UPDATE

Sorry for late response guys. Below is the exact code i am using. I've just tested this again and i am getting the same error.

Enpoint URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MY_USER@EMAIL/events/

```
// New rest client with the destination URL.
        var client = new RestClient(url);

        // Type of request
        var request = new RestRequest(requestType);

        // Headers
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


        // Content serialized in a json format  
        if (requestType == Method.POST || requestType == Method.PATCH || requestType == Method.PUT)
        {
            var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestContent);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }


        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
```

Body of the request

```
{"Id":null,"Subject":"Maths","UserEmailAddress":"sample@sample.onmicrosoft.com","Start":{"DateTime":"2016-09-1T10:11:56","TimeZone":"Pacific/Auckland"},"End":{"DateTime":"2016-09-1T11:11:56","TimeZone":"Pacific/Auckland"},"Location":null,"Body":null,"ReminderMinutesBeforeStart":60,"IsReminderOn":true}
```

Comment: Hi Thivy, Thanks for trying out Microsoft Graph. Would you mind sharing more information about this issue? Which endpoint are you trying to access? Can you share the request with us?

Comment: As you have already done, the mentioned error payload seems to valid JSON. Are your using the client SDK (if so, what platform?) ? If not, what library are you using to deserialize the JSON payload?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your deserialization code? The JSON itself is valid.

Answer (score 4):

The JSON text you posted actually contains the 3-byte UTF-8 BOM (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF). That will cause most JSON parsers to fail.

A simple workaround to your issue would be to detect the BOM and strip it before you parse.

Assuming JavaScript, something like below will solve your immediate issue.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// Reading the string into JavaScript will convert the BOM from the 3-byte
// version to the 2-byte version (0xFEFF).
json = json.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '');
```

-

**More**

It would be much more valuable to figure out why this is even getting appended to the resulting error in the first place. How are you making the request that results in this error? If this is from a webpage, what is the page encoding? Are you setting any other HTTP request headers that may pertain to the desired encoding?

Comment: Excellent catch. I copied and pasted the JSON from above but I clearly missed the BOM during the process. Unless there is, as you stated, something unique about how the REST endpoint is being called then there is clearly a bug here. A BOM should _not_ be included in a JSON payload; RFC 7159 mentions explicitly: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1

Comment: Also been bitten by this bug, was using Node.js server and was having it automatically parsing responses per content-type application/json, but kept getting JSON parsing errors when trying to decipher why a graph API call was not working. This was really frustrating trying to debug, please fix the error JSON to be valid!